# Is there any difference between 'body' and 'one' in these terms?

Tags: difference

We use 'body' and 'one' for referring to a person like: everyone, somebody, no one etc. So I want to know is there any difference in usage between them i.e:

- Everyone vs Everybody
- Someone vs Somebody
- No one vs Nobody
- Anyone vs Anybody

In other words, Is there any recommendation to choose one over another in what cases etc.

Comment: Don't expect downvotes for questions about the English language. That's why we're here. It's not a stupid question at all.

Comment: I  think there is a little difference, as far as I know, everyone is more specific than everybody.

Answer (score 4):

The two options are generally interchangeable. There may be some regional preferences. I believe that the -one options are considered to be slightly more formal and the -body forms slightly less formal.

As an example, here's an article from the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/anyone-anybody-or-anything) site specifically about "anyone" vs "anybody".

> Anyone and anybody have no difference in meaning. Anybody is a little less formal than anyone. Anyone is used more in writing than anybody

And, a [general guide](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-indefinite-body-one-thing-where) on indefinite pronouns that says the same:

> -body and -one mean the same thing. In informal contexts, we use indefinite pronouns ending in -body more often than pronouns ending in -one. The forms with -one are more common in formal writing

I tend to agree with this. Some people may have other thoughts.

Comment: And a [M-W editor](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/everybody-or-everyone) seems to agree with this as well.

Comment: Exactly. I'd add that the choice of one or the other is usually prosodic: which creates the more pleasing or more emphatic rhythm.